# StoryBook not reading a constant defined in a separate file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook

I'm using storybook 7.2.1 in my react project and I am getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GlobalVariables')";

GlobalVariables is a constant that I defined in file named global.variables.ts, this file in located under 'src/constant/'.

The 'constant' directory includes an index.ts file which exports all the constants that I defined in all the files under 'src/constant/'

I tried adding this to the main.js config file of storybook:

```
const config: StorybookConfig = {
...
staticDirs: ['..\\public', '../src/config/constant'],
...
}

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1):

`staticDirs` is used to serve [static files](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets#serving-static-files-via-storybook-configuration) like images, fonts,..etc.

if you have a set of variables that needs to be accessed from multiple places you can save them as `env` [variables](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/environment-variables#using-storybook-configuration):

```
// in your .storybook/main.ts

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  framework: '@storybook/your-framework',
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  env: (config) => ({
    ...config,
    EXAMPLE_VAR: 'An environment variable configured in Storybook',
  }),
};
```

then in your stories you can access them like:

```
export const Default: Story = {
  args: {
    exampleProp: process.env.EXAMPLE_VAR,
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there another way to keep the constants defined in the files under 'constant' directory and allow storybook to access them from there, since I have multiple constants defined in multiple files under '/constant' and it will require modification of hundreds of files where I'm importing them

Comment: @AlaBenAicha can you give me an example of how you are using `GlobalVariables ` in your code?

Comment: import { GlobalVariables } from 'config/constant';
const Component = () =>{
return(
<Button disabled={condition? GlobalVariables.TRUE : GlobalVariables.FALSE} />
)
}
export default Component ;